# Getting nil after delete an object in Coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I tried to store some data using CoreData.
I created entity name Users and some attributes namely age, username, password.
Successfully loading, retrieving.
When I delete some object in that entity using `context.delete(user)`, it will be deleted but show nil after I retrieve again.

[image: Showing nil for deleted object]

Note: I write the code for predicate with a format of "Username!=nil".
Is this the right way? How to overcome without nil in Core Data?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CoreDataVC: UIViewController {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate 
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func addAction(_ sender: Any){
        if let newUser = openDatabse(){
            saveData(UserDBObj:newUser)
        }
        _ = fetchData()
    }

    @IBAction func deleteAction(_ sender: Any){
        if let newUser = openDatabse(){
            deleteData(UserObj: newUser)
        }
        _ = fetchData()
    }

        // MARK: Methods to Open, Store and Fetch data
    func openDatabse() -> NSManagedObject?{
        context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Users", in: context) else {
            print("Invalid Entity")
            return nil
        }
        let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        return newUser
    }

    func deleteData(UserObj: NSManagedObject){
        let result = self.fetchData()
        if let data = result.last{
            context.delete(data)
        }
        do {
            try context.save()
        }
        catch{
            print("Error on saving context")
        }
        _ = fetchData()
    }

    func saveData(UserDBObj:NSManagedObject)
    {
        UserDBObj.setValue("RDC1", forKey: "username")
        UserDBObj.setValue("12341", forKey: "password")
        UserDBObj.setValue("22", forKey: "age")
        
        print("Storing Data..")
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Storing data Failed")
        }
        _ = fetchData()
    }

    func fetchData() -> [Users]
    {
        var users : [Users] = []
        print("Fetching Data..")
        let request = Users.fetchRequest()
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)
            users = result
            for data in result {//as! [NSManagedObject] {
                print("Username: ",data.username ?? "nil",", Age : ",data.age ?? "nil")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Fetching data Failed")
        }
        return users
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you save the changes?

Comment: Yes, I used context.save() after delete.

Comment: Well without code it’s difficult to give any advice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I updated my code above. Please check that

Comment: The error is pretty obvious, every time you call openDatabse you create a new User object which mean you delete this newly created object instead of an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

This is also happening to me, In my case, it is solved by creating a new fetch request for both delete and retrieve data.